# IMG KIT Not displaying Font Awesome Icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, imgkit

I have a little app that is using imgkit to create images for social media.

in the image I have a FontAwesome Icon that I cannot get to show.

I have imported the style directly into the view from the cdn like so.

app/views/quotes/show.png.erb

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>

 my styles are here

</style>

<div class="png-card-body">
  <h1 class="png-card-title"><%= @quote.quote %></h1>
  </br>
  <h6 class="png-card-text"><%= @quote.author %></h6>
  <div class ="png-card-footer">
    <p class="png-text-center"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> myapp</p>
  </div>
</div>
```